# How to make a figure bigger in Octave Jupyter notebook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, octave

I am trying to create a figure with several plots in an Octave Jupyter notebook but the figure becomes very small. How to make it bigger?

An example:

```
figure(1);
subplot(2, 2, 1);
x = -pi:0.1:pi;
plot(x, sin(x));
subplot(2, 2, 2);
x = -pi:0.1:pi;
plot(x, cos(x));

subplot(2, 2, 3);
x = -pi:0.1:pi;
plot(x, sin(2 * x));
subplot(2, 2, 4);
x = -pi:0.1:pi;
plot(x, cos(2 * x));
```

I would like this figure bigger.

Edit: Added screenshots.

[image: Small subplots]

[image: Big plot]

Comment: Could you please add a screenshot and mention what exactly is small? If it's the figure size, you could try `f = figure; f.Position = [100 100 540 400];`, where you can change the numbers to whatever size you require. I suspect that figures are embedded though, and might need changing withing the Jupyter, rather than Octave environment.

Comment: To follow on what Adriaan, a lot of time in Jupyter with Python kernel you save the plot as an image where you can control the resolution of that image you'll be saving & opening sort of separate from the default Jupyter display. (You can though display image there.)  ......  Did you try any of the example commands [here](https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel/issues/4#issuecomment-72928314) or [here](https://github.com/Calysto/octave_kernel/issues/98#issuecomment-390066829)? Discussed in the documentation [here](https://docs.octave.org/latest/Jupyter-Notebooks.html), look for 'width' there.

Comment: Yes, I tried out these %plot commands but then I get an error message: Inline plot failed, consider trying another graphics toolkit
error: print: rendering with fltk toolkit requires visible figure (DISPLAY='')
error: called from
    _make_figures>safe_print at line 125 column 7
    _make_figures at line 49 column 13